# IE8 cloneNode(true) object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone, deep-copy, clonenode

`$('#attachment-deletion').cloneNode(true);`

IE reports Object doesn't support this property or method

what can I do about this? cloneNode was my solution to IE8 not recognizing jquery's clone method, which it didn't even throw an error about

Comment: Have you tried: `$('#attachment-deletion')[0].cloneNode(true);` ?

Comment: or just `$('#attachment-deletion').clone(true);`

Comment: @roasted, a combination of element zero and converting back to jquery objects worked for me

Comment: so could you post the code which works for you?!

Comment: @roasted `var attachmentDeleteMainModalClone = $('#attachment-deletion')[0].cloneNode(true);`
   `$(attachmentDeleteMainModalClone).attr('id', 'attachment-deletion-'+'main');` not mentioned earlier is that I was having trouble also accessing the object after the clone method, now its all fixed

Comment: you could use then: `attachmentDeleteMainModalClone.id = 'attachment-deletion-main'`  even its properly change nothing. BTW, thx for sharing your solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cloneNode` is a native javascript method that doesn't work on jQuery objects, you have decide what to use :

jQuery

```
$('#attachment-deletion').clone(true);
```

or plain JS

```
document.getElementById('attachment-deletion').cloneNode(true);
```

Edit:
You can also Combine Plain JS with jQuery if you need to:

```
$('#attachment-deletion').get(0).cloneNode(true);
// or
$('#attachment-deletion')[0].cloneNode(true);
```

Comment: a combination of this answer with some other comments worked for me, thanks!